# Camel Bindy not able to marshal POJO into CSV

Tags: java, apache-camel

I'm trying to marshal a POJO into a CSV using camel-bindy, using the following setup:

```
<bean id="bindyDataFormat" class="org.apache.camel.dataformat.bindy.csv.BindyCsvDataFormat">
<constructor-arg value="com.foo.kod.domain" />
```

```
<camel:route>
  <camel:from uri="ref:kod.handler.list.in.csv" />
  <camel:choice>
    <camel:when>
      <camel:xpath>$Accept = 'application/json' </camel:xpath>
      <camel:to uri="bean:handlerListProcessor?method=process" />
      <camel:marshal ref="myJSON" />
    </camel:when>
    <camel:when>
      <camel:xpath>$Accept = 'text/csv' </camel:xpath>
      <camel:to uri="bean:handlerListProcessor?method=process" />
      <camel:marshal ref="bindyDataformat">
        <camel:bindy type="Csv" packages="com.foo.kod.domain"/>
      </camel:marshal>
    </camel:when>
    <camel:otherwise>
      <camel:to uri="bean:handlerListProcessor?method=process" />
      <camel:marshal ref="myJSON" />
    </camel:otherwise>
  </camel:choice>
</camel:route>
```

But this throws a ClassCastException each time:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.foo.kod.domain.Handler cannot be cast to java.util.Map
    at org.apache.camel.dataformat.bindy.csv.BindyCsvDataFormat.marshal(BindyCsvDataFormat.java:93)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.MarshalProcessor.process(MarshalProcessor.java:58)
    at org.apache.camel.impl.converter.AsyncProcessorTypeConverter$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorTypeConverter.java:50)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:78)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:98)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:89)
    at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:69)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:78)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:98)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:89)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.interceptor.TraceInterceptor.process(TraceInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:78)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.processNext(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:98)
    at org.apache.camel.processor.DelegateAsyncProcessor.process(DelegateAsyncProcessor.java:89)
    at org.apache.camel.fabric.FabricTraceProcessor.process(FabricTraceProcessor.java:81)
    at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorHelper.process(AsyncProcessorHelper.java:78)
```